# DIfference between binary and decimal MB to bytes converter

Tags: binary, byte, decimal

In the MB to bytes converter site , when i try to see the conversion , i saw below two answers , what is the difference ?

```
1 MB = 1000000 Bytes (in decimal)
1 MB = 1048576 Bytes (in binary)

https://www.gbmb.org/mb-to-bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

1048576 = 1024 x 1024

The first one is more human friendly using decimal calculation. Usually seen on the product package showing SSD or USB storage's capacity in consumer electronics field.

```
1MB = 1000kB = 1000x1000B
```

The latter one is used in computer science or real circuit which uses binary calculation (2^n).

```
1MB = 1024kB = 1024x1024B
```